# Unable to send client side log to server (Asp.net Web API) using log4javascript

Tags: c#, logging, log4javascript, jsnlog

**Requirement:**
Add client side logging and send it to server. Devs in server should be able to enable or disable this logging functionality.

**My Approach:**
I have created a ASP.NET WebAPI project, where i have created a POST method to write log data to a local file. So, that i can add and monitor client side logs.

Now, From the client side i am not able to call the post method. I have used log4javascript. There i got AjaxAppender to send request to server.

**JS code using log4javascript:**

```
// Create the logger
var log = log4javascript.getLogger();

// Create a AjaxAppender with default options
var ajaxAppender = new log4javascript.AjaxAppender('http://localhost:59132/api/log');

// If you want to send JSON
var jsonLayout = new log4javascript.JsonLayout();

// Add configuration for ajaxAppender
//ajaxAppender.setThreshold(log4javascript.Level.ERROR); // Sets the appender's threshold. Log messages of level less severe than this threshold will not be logged.
//ajaxAppender.setBatchSize(10); // Sets the number of log messages to send in each request.
//ajaxAppender.sendAll(); // send all remaining messages on window.beforeunload()
ajaxAppender.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
ajaxAppender.setLayout(jsonLayout);

// Adds the given appender
log.addAppender(ajaxAppender);

// Log message
log.debug("Debug");
log.info("Info");
log.warn("Warning");
log.error("Error");
log.fatal("Fatal");
```

**Server Side Code:**

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody]List<string> value)
{
    string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Log.txt";
    foreach(string s in value)
    {
        using (StreamWriter writetext = new StreamWriter(path, true))
        {
            writetext.WriteLine("Log: " + s.ToString() + " " + DateTime.Now);
        }
    }
}
```

Moreover,
Using jQuery Ajax i am able to send log messages, but i don't think i should implement this in my project, because i am storing the logs in an array and I don't have any configuration set(i.e. I will not be able to enable and disable JS logging feature).

**JS Code using jQuery Ajax:**

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var logArr = [];
    logArr.push("Error - XYZ " + "URL: " +  window.location.href);
    logArr.push("Info - PQRS " + "URL: " + window.location.href);
    logArr.push("Warning - MNOP " + "URL: " +  window.location.href);
    sendError(logArr)
    });

function sendError(message) {
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/log",
    type: 'POST',
    async: true,
    data: JSON.stringify(message),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function () {
        console.log("Success");
    },
    error: function (e) {
        console.log("Failure " + e.message);
    }
});
}
```

Can log4JS, JSNLog can resolve this? Please, guide me here.

**NOTE:** We will not be using any error tracking tool like: errlytics, rollbar etc. As they are paid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am the author of JSNLog.

JSNLog includes a server side end point for .Net that will log to your favorite logging package (Serilog, Log4Net, etc.) It supports both ASP.NET CORE and ASP.NET Framework (the non-Core version of ASP.NET). It has many great (in my biased opinion) features:
http://jsnlog.com

I understand you want to give the server side developers control over the server side logging. With JSNLog, the *client* side loggers can be controlled with *server* side code. For details on how this works, see:
http://jsnlog.com/Documentation/Configuration/OnServer

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have implemented JSNLog in my project. And its working like a champ.

Comment: Hi Matt, I am facing issue while implementing JSNLog in MVC app for .NET 4.5, can you please help me here. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51982482/unable-to-implement-jsnlog-on-net-4-5-mvc-application